# Typescript: Make type dependent on value of variable

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
interface ObjectWithLorem {
    lorem: string;
}

interface ObjectWithIpsum {
    ipsum: string;
}

type KeyName = 'lorem' | 'ipsum';

const key: KeyName = 'lorem';

type Object = key === 'lorem' ? ObjectWithLorem : ObjectWithIpsum;

const object: Object = {
    lorem: 'Lorem'
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFgOrBgAWAMgPZQQC2yA3gFDJPIA2F1AXMgM5hSgBzANz0AvvXqhIsRCgzZcBYgEkADtwCuNBs2TB1Wrr34hhYiWACeqlAGkIlgHJwqKALzIA5G0pVPyAB8vfU0-EXoEMhBeZABrBy57Jxd3Lx9qT3CrGzQsHDBkD3jLQrcPb3Y-ZAB+XIV8QlJK5C55fKUiNVDwyOiCsjzcVsGCjx1mdKouT3JfTzEgA)

This is obviously not working, but I was wondering if there was either a way to make it work as-is, or at least an alternative solution to have the same effect - essentially the `Object` type should either be an `ObjectWithLorem` or `ObjectWithIpsum` interface, depending on whether the `key` variable is `lorem` or not.

Comment: Types are for compile-time checks and access enforcement. So you can say something is `ObjectWithLorem | ObjectWithIpsum` (one or the other), but to *use* it you need to narrow the type to know which property to access. Can you show more of how you want to *use* this?

Comment: This can be done with a union of tuples you can generate from a map of keys to interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

If we've got our keys and interfaces, let's map each key to the corresponding interface:

```
type KeyToInterfaceMap = {
    lorem: ObjectWithLorem;
    ipsum: ObjectWithIpsum;
};
```

Then we use a mapped type to get our possible tuples:

```
type PossibleTuples = {
    [K in keyof KeyToInterfaceMap]: [K, KeyToInterfaceMap[K]];
}[keyof KeyToInterfaceMap];
```

Now say if you've got a variable of type `PossibleTuples`, maybe like this:

```
declare const checkMe: PossibleTuples;
```

We can do what you want just like this:

```
const [key, obj] = checkMe;

if (key === "lorem") {
    obj // inferred as ObjectWithLorem
}
```

You can explore more with this method below:

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WKqjZN)